# Where are the postgreSQL files after a db:migrate in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite, postgresql

When working with SQLite3, after I run `bundle exec rake db:migrate`, it updates the `development.sqlite3` file in the `db` folder (itself in my app folder).

I configured my Rails app to work with PostgreSQL, the databases and migrations work fine but I don't know where the associated files are created. Instead, I still see the same .sqlite3 files.

Any idea where they are lodged, or maybe they're not even created? And why the .sqlite3 are still created if I run Rails with PostgreSQL?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PostgreSQL does not have "a single" file with all the data, structure,... basically the whole database. This is the (dis-)advantage of SQLite: it has everything in a single file that makes development very easy.

Depending on your platform, you have a postgresql folder somewhere where all data, table structures, indexes,... are stored. On Ubuntu, the location is per default

```
/var/lib/postgresql/{pg_version}/main
```

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL is a database server. Rails sends it commands, it executes them. Where it stores data files is configured in its configuration files. This is none of Rails' business.

For example, for MySQL default data dir is `/var/lib/mysql`. For Postgres it must something similar. To know exact location consult your db server config files.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 8 I found the database in
`C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\data\`